# Visual Studio holding onto references that have been removed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I get this as a warning when I build the solution. The weird part is that I removed those references long ago when I realized I didn't need them.

"Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Somenamespace.AnotherNamespace" that could not be resolved

I tried a Clean Solution then rebuild but no difference. I checked the solution and project files as well to see if there was a leftover reference but nothing. How do I clean this up?

Note: this is VS2017

Comment: Your solution either has multiple projects with contain different versions of that assembly, or your projects have dependencies that depend on different versions of that assembly.

Comment: @Amy Negative. There is only one project in the solution. Plus, as I said, those references were removed long ago.

Comment: Then you have dependencies that depend on multiple versions of that assembly.  There was an `or` in my first comment.

Comment: Set build logging to the highest verbosity, then do a rebuild.  Search for that assembly name in the output.  This should help shed some light on the issue.

Comment: @Amy That did help but didn't really explain what was going on. I'll answer the question below

Comment: Were you going to post an answer?  I'm curious what the issue was and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure nuget packages you use do not have discrepancies in their version. if so, you will either need to do assembly rebinding or use the exact same version across the solution. You can use the later by means of the “Consolidate” of the nuget package manager at the solution level.

Comment: so if I got into the Consolidate tab and there is nothing showing up? That would mean there are no discrepancies no?

Comment: @snappymcsnap Your conclusion is reasonable, but incorrect.  Consolidate only works on dependencies that are, themselves, nuget packages.  Not all dependencies are like that.  Some libraries simply embed their dependencies.